# How do you draw an arrow at the end of a bezier curve in SVG / raphael?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I have a curve generated by this:

```
    var path = ["M", x1.toFixed(3), y1.toFixed(3), "L", arrow_left_x, arrow_left_y, "L", arrow_right_x, arrow_right_y, "L", x1.toFixed(3), y1.toFixed(3), "C", x2, y2, x3, y3, x4.toFixed(3), y4.toFixed(3)].join(",");
```

[image]

but my arrow is not correctly done.
- it only points to the right, and doesn't point the same direction as the slope of the curve at the end of the bezier. 
- it is not filled

now, I know I'm not doing the math correctly here, but mainly, I just want to know how to fill the triangle at the end of the line. thanks!

For demo purposes:

```
        arrow_left_x = (x1 - 8);
        arrow_left_y = (y1 - 8);
        arrow_right_x = (x1 - 8);
        arrow_right_y = (y1 + 8);
```

that is the code for getting the the coordinates I use.

Comment: See also _[Arrow triangles on my SVG line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808860/arrow-triangles-on-my-svg-line)_.

Comment: Now Raphael 2.1 has a path attr pair for this, `arrow-start` and `arrow-end`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372513/raphaeljs-how-to-draw-arrow-heads-at-the-end-of-archs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you should use markers for your purpose. See an [example here](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_patterns.html#markers).

**Edit:**

You need to create a marker in the `defs` section:

```
var defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
var marker = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'marker');
marker.setAttribute('id', 'Triangle');
marker.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 16 16');
marker.setAttribute('refX', '0');
marker.setAttribute('refY', '6');
marker.setAttribute('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth');
marker.setAttribute('markerWidth', '16');
marker.setAttribute('markerHeight', '12');
marker.setAttribute('orient', 'auto');
var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
marker.appendChild(path); 
path.setAttribute('d', 'M 0 0 L 16 8 L 0 16 z');   
path.setAttribute('stroke', '#000');   
path.setAttribute('stroke-width', '1'); 
path.setAttribute('style', '  marker-start :none;   marker-end :none; ');      

document.getElementById( id_of_svg_placeholder ).getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(defs);
defs.appendChild(marker);
```

and referense it in CSS:

```
path {marker-start:url("#Triangle")}
```

or as an attribute:

```
<path d="..." marker-start="url(#Triangle)" />
```

[Here's the resulting jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G5mTx/29/)

Comment: alright, I see how it works now. However, it is not campatible with Raphael, as it uses a tag, rather than an attribute, if you edit your answer somehow, I'll change the down vote to an upvote. OR if you can figure out how to get the markers in here : http://jsfiddle.net/G5mTx/10/ that wolud be awesome

Comment: I hope this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/G5mTx/29/ . Don't be afraid to use native DOM methods. And probably it's Raphael that is not compatible with creating SVG markers, not the other way round. Also, I guess it's not too friendly to downvote someone who offered his help and gave a key to your question.

Comment: I can't upvote unless you edit your answer though. =\ that's exactly what I need though! You are awesome! <3

Comment: thanks! thas was pretty easy to implement into my new code, too: http://jsfiddle.net/G5mTx/30/

Comment: "it's not too friendly to downvote someone who offered his help" #TrueStory

Comment: The order of lines is not good, it should be like this: var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path'); THEN multiple lines of path.setAttribute(...); THEN marker.appendChild(path);  and THEN defs.appendChild(marker); and LASTLY ....getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(defs);