# How to add custom colors in D3 nodes of a graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

[image]

I am using D3 api for a graph where a couple of nodes are forming from a parent node i want to color the nodes of  the whole graph in a manner that each parent node has a fixed color and the child nodes has different color i.e a root node always have red color and the left child is blue and the right one is green and if only one child is there it is green .I am using this api ,,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.27.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?1.27.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?1.27.1"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

 line.link {
  stroke: #ccc;
}

circle.node {
 fill: #000;
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   var w = 960,
  h = 500,
  r = d3.scale.sqrt().domain([0, 20000]).range([0, 20]);

 var force = d3.layout.force()
.gravity(.01)
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(60)
.size([w, h]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);

d3.xml("flare.xml", "application/xml", function(xml) {
  var nodes = self.nodes = d3.select(xml).selectAll("*")[0],
    links = self.links = nodes.slice(1).map(function(d) {
      return {source: d, target: d.parentNode};
     });

  force
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll("line.link")
  .data(links)
.enter().append("svg:line")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
  .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
  .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
  .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return r(d.textContent) || 5; })
  .call(force.drag);

    force.on("tick", function() {
    nodes[0].x = w / 2;
    nodes[0].y = h / 2;

   link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
     });
    });

    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

can anyone help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG has its own CSS properties, one of which being `fill`. It sets the fill color of an SVG element.

Here is how you use it with D3:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("svg:circle")
  .style("fill", function (d) { return '#1f77b4'; })
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return r(d.textContent) || 5; })
  .call(force.drag);
```

Here the color value (`#1f77b4`) will be the same for all nodes. If you want to color your nodes with a specific algorithm, D3 ships with predefined [categorical color scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#categorical-colors).

Edit: Here is [a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006712/d3js-fill-color). One of its answers [has a good custom ordinal color scale example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13013162/1798491).

Comment: thanks for your answer it is working i get all nodes in blue color..if i want to add custom color in nodes i will have to put a condition write?

Comment: Yes. You have to decide how each node will be colored by changing the return value in `.style("fill", function (d) { return '#1f77b4'; })`. You could directly put the color in your XML file, or map colors to values of attributes already in your XML (see [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006712/d3js-fill-color/13013162#13013162)).

Comment: i can not change the data here or can not use an XML file i have to put a condition that will decide which node is root and which is child

Comment: var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 8)
        //.style("fill", function(d,i) { return d3.scale.category20(i); })
        .style("fill",function(d,i){
         
         return d3.scale.category20(i);
        })
        .call(force.drag); i am doing this can you help from here??

Comment: That's the way to go, but `d3.scale.category20(i)` won't work. It should be `d3.scale.category20()(i)`, because `d3.scale.category20()` returns the scale function.

Comment: thanks for your help it worked fine ,,can you help a little about this arrowheads???

Comment: You are using SVG lines for the edges, so [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680166/how-to-use-an-arrow-marker-on-an-svg-line-element) may help you. Good luck.