# Marker arrows alignment in d3.js tree diagram

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am drawing tree diagram using `d3.js`. I have circular nodes and my path end points are the center point of circles. 
I want to add marker arrows for the paths , if I give **refX** and **refY** properties as 0 marker is aligned properly but it wont be visible since my circle will overlap that.
I refered [this][2] question and calculated **refX refY** according to that

But still I am not getting the arrows well oriented and when I drag the node arrows are getting messed up still more .

Currently I am using `noderadius` as 16 and `markerwidth` and `height` as 6 (which is configurable)

I am using radial, horizontal and vertical views for the same tree. Can anyone give me a solution to draw these arrows with proper alignment and orientation?

[This is how my diagram looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urjyZ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display an arrow head in the middle of D3 force layout link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729856/display-an-arrow-head-in-the-middle-of-d3-force-layout-link)

Comment: Not force layout tree diagram.  And I am trying to put the arrow next to the node. Not on middle. actually I have tried that answer also. But marker-mid property was not working for me

Comment: how are you currently appending the arrows ? Perhaps put your code into a fiddle so we can take a look

Comment: I have added the code in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fp60gmj1/

Comment: working code : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/fp60gmj1/3/ , you cant use .attr("refY", -())

Comment: Sorry. I had updated the code there but missed to change the link here

Comment: I think I found a temporary solution for my problem. Instead of drawing the links between centre of node circles now I am restricting the lines till the circle surface . Now it looks properly oriented. Thanks for the responses.. Updated the code in fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/fp60gmj1/8/