# DataMaps.js - Network Weather-map (inbound and outbound arcs)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, datamaps

I am trying to use Datamaps using the arcs and circles option to create a network weathermap.

The basic issue I'm hitting is that there are inbound and outbound connections in a network and I'd like to be able to visualize them as separate entities. To avoid the incoming and outgoing overlapping, I tried doing a simple longitude and latitude offset (- .2 each) to "offset" the path. What I'm seeing is that they cross-over each other.

Any ideas on how I might be able to do this?

[Current Map Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts5Ak.png)

Comment: What if you created a second arc generator (if this is what is happening), and make one larger than the other? That way they would not overlap, but would still be somewhat distinct.

Comment: you could use a color transition on the arcs, i.e. when arc is going out, you use green and when arc is coming in, you transition the color to red or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue take a look at https://github.com/cpmarvin/d3js_weathermap. If you have parallel links then you need get the nr of links btw nodes and do an offset. Take a look at https://github.com/cpmarvin/d3js

Hope it helps.

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
    //find middle value of the link and calculate path
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    var endX = (d.target.x + d.source.x) / 2;
    var endY = (d.target.y + d.source.y) / 2;

    var len = dr - ((dr/2) * Math.sqrt(3));
    endX = endX + (1 * len/dr);
    endY = endY + (-1 * len/dr);

    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + endX + "," + endY;
} )
```

this is based on :

[Display an arrow head in the middle of D3 force layout link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729856/display-an-arrow-head-in-the-middle-of-d3-force-layout-link)

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers: if the link gets broken, the answer becomes irrelevant. Instead, put the most important parts to your post directly and make sure the result is an answer, not a comment.