# Change orientation of Arrow Marker in D3 oriented force graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to insert an arrow marker in each one of my links. But I would like to change the orientation of the arrows, make them face the other end of each link.

Here's the code:

```
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
      .enter().append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", "end")    // This section adds in the arrows
        .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
        .attr("refX", 15)
        .attr("refY", -1.5)
        .attr("markerWidth", 6)
        .attr("markerHeight", 6)
        .attr("orient", 180)
      .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    // add the links and the arrows
    var pg = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
        .data(force.links())
      .enter().append("g");

    var path = pg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
```

how is that possible?

I've tried to change `.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");`

for `.attr("marker-end", "url(#start)");`

but then the markers just dissapear. One more thing I would like to know is what part of the code defines the curvature of the links and how to change that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the `"orient"` attribute of markers: https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/#OrientAttribute

in your case something like: `.attr("orient", "auto-start-reverse")` or `.attr("orient", 180)` would work.

An example can be found at this post: [Display an arrow head in the middle of D3 force layout link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729856/display-an-arrow-head-in-the-middle-of-d3-force-layout-link)

As for the curvature, the related part is

```
dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

as dr, the radius, gets bigger there will be more curve.

Comment: The .attr("orient", "auto-start-reverse") made no effect ):

Comment: It actually works, but only with `.attr("marker-start", "url(#end)")`.

When I try `.attr("marker-mid", "url(#end)")` it dissapears ):

Comment: I've inserted my code into the original post. Would you try it in your environment to see if it works? Thanks

Comment: why there are so many appends? `var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
          .enter().append("svg:path")`

Comment: Even if I delete the pg and the text and paste your code, the arrows doesn't appear.

Comment: @LucasLourenço I think you are missing the calculation of the mid point in the tick event. Are you defining your midpoint?

Comment: No. Im just using `"marker-mid"` Do I have to define it? When I use `.attr("orient", "auto")` and `"marker-mid"` it works...

Comment: Well, I've managed by changing the `.attr("refX",80)` on the markers.

Answer (score 1):

```
svg.select("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "start")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", -5)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)    
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,0L10,-5L10,5");

var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-start", "url(#start)")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

```js
var links= [
  {
    "source": "Harry",
    "target": "Sally",
    "value": 1.2
  },
  {
    "source": "Harry",
    "target": "Mario",
    "value": 1.3
  },
  {
    "source": "Sarah",
    "target": "Alice",
    "value": 0.2
  },
  {
    "source": "Eveie",
    "target": "Alice",
    "value": 0.5
  },
  {
    "source": "Peter",
    "target": "Alice",
    "value": 1.6
  },
  {
    "source": "Mario",
    "target": "Alice",
    "value": 0.4
  },
  {
    "source": "James",
    "target": "Alice",
    "value": 0.6
  },
  {
    "source": "Harry",
    "target": "Carol",
    "value": 0.7
  },
  {
    "source": "Harry",
    "target": "Nicky",
    "value": 0.8
  },
  {
    "source": "Bobby",
    "target": "Frank",
    "value": 0.8
  },
  {
    "source": "Alice",
    "target": "Mario",
    "value": 0.7
  },
  {
    "source": "Harry",
    "target": "Lynne",
    "value": 0.5
  },
  {
    "source": "Sarah",
    "target": "James",
    "value": 1.9
  },
  {
    "source": "Roger",
    "target": "James",
    "value": 1.1
  },
  {
    "source": "Maddy",
    "target": "James",
    "value": 0.3
  },
  {
    "source": "Sonny",
    "target": "Roger",
    "value": 0.5
  },
  {
    "source": "James",
    "target": "Roger",
    "value": 1.5
  },
  {
    "source": "Alice",
    "target": "Peter",
    "value": 1.1
  },
  {
    "source": "Johan",
    "target": "Peter",
    "value": 1.6
  },
  {
    "source": "Alice",
    "target": "Eveie",
    "value": 0.5
  },
  {
    "source": "Harry",
    "target": "Eveie",
    "value": 0.1
  }
];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || 
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || 
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
    link.value = +link.value;
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

svg.select("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "start")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", -5)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)    
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,0L10,-5L10,5");

// add the links and the arrows
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-start", "url(#start)")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

// define the nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

// add the nodes
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5);

// add the text 
node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// add the curvy lines
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + 
            d.source.x + "," + 
            d.source.y + "A" + 
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
            d.target.x + "," + 
            d.target.y;
    });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
       return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
```

```css
path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  fill: #000;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```