# RaphaelJS - how to draw arrow-heads at the end of archs?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, raphael

I'm working on a project using raphaelJS, I'm trying to draw arrows at both ends of an arch and while I have the arch down, but it's hard to get arrows.

Thanks in advance for any input!

**the issue: how do you draw arrows at the end of curved raphael lines?**

- [The mockup](http://puu.sh/dn9dg/8c97418cc0.png)
- [What I got so far, in a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a62kxyk3/2/)

**The Body Tag**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="arrows"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The Coffeescript/Javascript**

```coffee
window.ready = ->
  $canvas = $('body').find '#arrows'
  paper = Raphael $canvas[0], 500, 500

  WIDTH = 500
  HEIGHT = 500
  center = [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2]
  radius = 230
  stroke = 5

  paper.customAttributes.arc = (center_x, center_y, degrees, radius) ->
    return unless radius
    radians = (90 - degrees) * Math.PI / 180
    arc_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos radians
    arc_y = center_y - radius * Math.sin radians
    path = [
      ['M', center_x, center_y - radius]
      ['M', center_x, center_y - radius]
      ['A', radius, radius, 0, +(degrees > 180), 1, arc_x, arc_y]
    ]
    return {path}

  arrow_1 = paper.path()
  arrow_1.node.setAttribute 'class', 'arrow_1'
  arrow_1.attr {arc: [center[0], center[1], 80, radius]}
  arrow_1.rotate 80, center[1], center[0]
```

**THE CSS**

```
#arrows {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
#arrows circle,
#arrows path {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

Comment: refer here http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html. Very clean and nice intro. It shows how to draw arrow head.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are happy to switch to Raphael 2.1.0 you can simply use the arrow-end attribute.
So you would add this...

```
arrow_1.attr({ 'arrow-end':   'classic-wide-long', 
               'arrow-start': 'classic-wide-long' });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a62kxyk3/3/)

Docs for this bit (look under attr)

[raph doc](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr)

Comment: Oddly, the current Raphael docs only list `arrow-end`, not `arrow-start`. Fortunately, this seems to be a documentation error, as it works. At first I thought I was missing something fundamental which would explain why paths only had arrows at the end!